# Rename multiple files in terminal

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

I have 40 mp4 files in a folder.

Every file starts with `video_`. Every file is of format `video_*.mp4`.

I need to rename all the files with `video_` removed from the begining of every file. How can I do that from terminal?

Comment: @JacobVlijm I know we have lots of these questions. But for a newbie it is not clear how to use the other answer. And this is not quite a duplicate.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can do it by a terminal command in a directory where these files are located.

```
rename 's/^video_//' *.mp4
```

That means select all filenames started with `video_` and replace `video_` with nothing. I guess `s` is for "substitute".

`^` shows the beginning of string. If you omit `^`, the first occurrence of `video_` will be removed no matter where it is located in the string. But in your case it does not really matter.

**Note**: Ubuntu versions above 17.04 don't ship with `rename` package, however you can still install it from default repositories via `sudo apt install rename`

Comment: or `rename 's/^.*?_//' *.mp4`

Comment: `Every file starts with video_. Every file is of format video_*.mp4.`

Comment: what does `s/` and `//` mean in `rename 's/^video_//' *.mp4` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Ah you're right, my bad. Then, if we're golfing, `rename 's/.*?_//' *.mp4` ;)

Comment: @kashish You can read the duplicate link. There is a good explanation.

Answer (score 8):

- Using `rename` (`prename`) :

  ```
  rename -n 's/^video_//' video_*.mp4
  ```

  If you are satisfies with the changes that are going to be made, remove `-n` to let the operation happens actually :

  ```
  rename 's/^video_//' video_*.mp4
  ```
- Using `bash` parameter expansion :

  ```
  for file in video_*.mp4; do mv -i "$file" "${file#video_}"; done
  ```

  - `${file#video_}` is the parameter expansion pattern to remove `video_` from the start of the file names.

  Or

  ```
  for file in video_*.mp4; do mv -i "$file" "${file/video_/}"; done
  ```

  - This one assumes `video_` comes only once in file names
  - `${file/video_/}` is a `bash` parameter expansion pattern that will replace `video_` from file names with blank.

Answer (score 3):

Using `rename`

```
rename 's/^video_//' *.mp4
```